# How to define $data variables that are accessible by all functions inside the controller?

Tags: codeigniter-3

If possible I would like to define values in $data once that are then accessible in any of the functions of the controller. Currently when I run the code none of these are accessible.

To clarify, when I was searching online, most answers are explaining how to globally define the variables for the entire application, I would like to specify that I need it only in the controller.

Codeigniter 3
Background of myself: I have no experience with coding but i'm eager to learn.

What I've done:

I attempted to add it in the controller at the start and make it public

I attempted to add it inside the __construct function

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public $data = [];
    public $footerScripts = [];

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        //Authentication required for this controller
        if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
        {
            //if not loggedin, reroute to the login page
            redirect('Auth/login', 'refresh');
        }

        $this->load->helper('sys');
        $this->load->helper('array');

        //set global information this is then overwritten by the individual functions
        $this->data['pageTitle'] = 'Pages';
        $this->data['activeNav'] = 'pages';
        $this->data['controllerIcon'] = 'flaticon-interface-6';

    }

    public function index()
    {
        //index doesn't always exist, instead we use list
        redirect(base_url('backend/pages/list'));
    }

    public function list()
    {
        $data = [];

        $data['view'] = "backend/defaultTheme/pages/list";
        $this->load->view('backend/defaultTheme/master/master2.php', $data);
    }

}
```

Desired result:

I want to declare the name of the controller so it can be used on all views, except if one of the functions wants to overwrite it.

```
$this->data['pageTitle'] = 'Pages';
```

and in the view I would like to:

```
echo $pageTitle;
```

Without having to declare it in every function of the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is pretty much setup correctly.

You have defined your property (that is what it is called ) $data so that is accessible to ALL Methods (functions) in your class and only in this class.

```
public $data = []; // $data property
```

It appears you are having issues with your list method.
This is what you currently have with comments I have included...

```
public function list()
{
    $data = []; // This is not needed as we have $this->data

    $data['view'] = "backend/defaultTheme/pages/list"; // This is just a string 
    $this->load->view('backend/defaultTheme/master/master2.php', $data); // Needs to reference the $this->data
}
```

So it would become something like...

```
public function list()
{
    // Load the subview
    $this->data['view'] = $this->load->view('backend/defaultTheme/pages/list',NULL,TRUE);
    // Display the final page
    $this->load->view('backend/defaultTheme/master/master2.php', $this->data); 
}
```

The property `$this->data` is accessible to every method(function) in the class.

You will see I have used this

```
$this->data['view'] = $this->load->view('backend/defaultTheme/pages/list',NULL,TRUE);
```

As you already know, the 2nd parameter is the page data (variables) and in this case they are NULL or just ''. The 3rd parameter, when set to true (defaults to false), will not display the view but will save it's contents. In this case into `$this->data['view']`.

That should get you thinking.

You should read the codeigniter userguide and I still do to this day.

Comment: Hello Tim Brown law, thank you for the response with structured information. It definetly is helping me understand the situation more.

I'll make sure to read the userguide on this, however, out of all the documentation I google I found that there are a lot of different methods of implementation. I'd like to use one to get a bit of experience in because if I don't practice it, I fear I might loose most of what I read.

I made the changes however, now i'm getting the "Undefined variable: data" perhaps something else is up here?